# an issue on R implementation for computing confidence interval

Tags: r

I once read the following R function for computing confidence interval

```
#  set number of simulated data sets and sample size
#  mu is the mean for the normal 
   S <- 1000 
   n <- 15
   mu <- 1
```

coverage of usual confidence interval based on sample mean is computed as follows. Here, `sampmean.ses` denotes the standard error for sample mean. I can mostly guess the logic behind this. What confuses me is about the way that R implements this, in specific, what does `outsampmean-t05*sampmean.ses <= mu` intend to do? Looks like sum is to count all of the discrete points satisfying these two conditions.

```
  t05 <- qt(0.975,n-1)
  coverage <- sum((outsampmean-t05*sampmean.ses <= mu) & 
      (outsampmean+t05*sampmean.ses >= mu))/S
```

Comment: Did you forget to include some code, or other information, in this question? I can't quite make sense of this.

Comment: It looks like a pedagogical example, showing how many times out of 1000 the confidence interval includes the true mean, where the simulation of the data sets and calculation of the mean and se of each data set is not shown.

Answer (score 2):

```
S       <- 1000 
n       <- 15   
mu      <- 1    
sigma   <- 50    
set.seed(1)
matdat       <- matrix(rnorm(S*n, mean = mu, sd = sigma), nrow=S)
outsampmean  <- rowSums(matdat)/n
sampmean.ses <- sqrt(rowSums((matdat-outsampmean)^2)/(n*(n-1)))
t05          <- qt(0.975,n-1)
coverage     <- sum((outsampmean-t05*sampmean.ses <= mu) & 
                    (outsampmean+t05*sampmean.ses >= mu))/S
```

will produce

```
> coverage
[1] 0.946
```

`outsampmean-t05*sampmean.ses <= mu` produces a TRUE or FALSE (effectively a 1 or 0 in the sum) depending on whether the lower boundary of the confidence interval calculated from the outcome sample mean and sample mean standard error is below or above the population mean.